# identifying when items are in view and out of view on website

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, offset

I am building some code to try and have something happen when an image is within view, then reset the counter when the image isnt in view and have that same thing happen again if the image returns to view.

I have the code working to recognize when the image comes into view and do something, but then when I add the code to reset the counter when the image is out of view the whole thing stops working.

html:

```
<div style="height: 2000px">
<img  height="320px" width= "240px" id="pbr" src="http://i47.tinypic.com/33bztj8.jpg" alt="image 1">
<img height="320px" width= "240px" id="pbrglow" src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2ykduvl.jpg" alt="image 2">
<button id="button">click to reset</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
#pbr {
    position: absolute;   
    top: 500px;
    z-index: 0;
}
#pbrglow {
    position: absolute;             
    display: none;
    top: 500px;
    z-index: 1;

}
#button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 850px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

javascript:

```
var y = $("#pbr").offset().top;
var eventsFired = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $("#pbr").offset().top;
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY + 100 > y && eventsFired == 0) {
        eventsFired++;
        alert(eventsFired);
    }
});


$("#button").on("click", function() {
    var scrollYY = $(window).offsetTop();
    if (eventsFired == 1) {
        alert("happened");
        eventsFired = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esegev1/ZwJpw/9/) with the code

Once I remove the code starting in $("#button")... the code works, but with this in the code doesnt.

P.S. this is a website I need to work on iOS.

Comment: I know you said you are targeting iOS, but have you tried it in other browsers? Which does it work in, and where does it not work? Any JS errors in the console?

Comment: the reason I am running it on iOS is becuase this is being used as a demo I am showing someone on my phone. I keep getting an error saying: ReferenceError: resetfunction is not defined @ fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:1. Not sure why it says I am not defining the function. updated jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/esegev1/ZwJpw/7/

Comment: In your example, your html has resetfunction() being called when the button is clicked. But you never define resetfunction anywhere.  And my comment about iOS wasn't that you should not be using iOS, but that you can test on a non-iOS browser to help diagnose problems.

Comment: So thats what I am a bit unclear about. down in the javascript, where I have the code function resetfunction(), isnt that defining the function? Sorry I am pretty new still. I changed the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/esegev1/ZwJpw/9/

Comment: I see no reference at all to `function resetfunction()`

Comment: I thought possibly, the word function was throwing something off so I changed it to resetevent (sorry for being so all over the map with you here) but in the html i am now calling resetevent(); and in the javascript i have function resetevent() and I am still getting the error that the function is undefined.

Comment: your js fiddle link above must be old, because there is no resetevent function defined either.

Comment: I edited the code, but the jsfiddle there was old and the new one is also about 3 comments up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `#button` click handler is throwing an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'offsetTop'`

You can see it on the jsFiddle page if you have a console open (you can enable the console for mobile Safari via Settings->Safari->Developer).

That problem is that `$(window)` doesn't have an `offsetTop()` method. If you get rid of that line (and you don't need it anyway, since you're never using `scrollYY`), everything works.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I removed the offsetTop() line but it still doesn't work. I also realized I wasn't calling the function from the html button. but now that I added that code its still not working. when I click the button under the image it should open an alert. Would you mind looking at the updated jsfiddle and see if you see any issues. thanks.  http://jsfiddle.net/esegev1/ZwJpw/7/

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I click the button --
[13:23:49.415] ReferenceError: resetfunction is not defined @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:1. not sure how I need to "define" it.

Comment: The error happens because the browser can't find `resetfunction`. Perhaps normally (i.e. not inside a jsFiddle) it might work as you've got it, bc `resetfunction` would be part of the global scope. But, even if it were to work, putting and calling functions through the global scope is not very good form. It's better to take out the `onclick="resetfunction();"` bit, and subscribe to the button click event via javascript: `$('button').click(resetfunction);` (just add this line somewhere in your code). Also, you ought to wrap all the code in $.ready(function() { /* all your code here */ });